# CLI Tool to extract images from video slideshow

Tags: video, images

I'm looking for a tool that can take a video (mp4) that is composed of about 50 still images and extract all of the images out of that video. Is there anything like this that exists?

Comment: `ffmpeg`. [This question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786669/extract-all-video-frames-as-images-with-ffmpeg/34786929).